# Calling a function in a separate file in Python

Tags: python, function

I've read the following posts:

[Importing Module or From Module Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/import-module-or-from-module-import)

[From file.py import *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450930/from-import-from-module)

And I was just wondering how to know when to break-up my code into multiple files versus putting many functions in one file?  My specific problem here is that I have a function with 100 lines that I want to call in the for-loop of another function.  Also, when are scripts executed? When you import them, or when you call them?

**Note: The answers below have fully solved the problem. Thank you!**

Comment: Why the downvote?  Per http://stackoverflow.com/faq, this is a "practicable, answerable problem unique to the programming profession" and a "specific programming problem." Is there a reason for it?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask: "Do your homework. Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?" Importing is a basic aspect of Python, well covered in the tutorial and elsewhere. We're *not* here to read the tutorial for you.

Comment: Upvoting the question as I've decided that Kev is not a real moderator

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming that the function `useful_function` is in a file `foreign_code.py` in the same directory as your program file, just put

```
from foreign_code import useful_function
```

at the top of your program.

Comment: What about the case when program that is using the function and program that is defining the function are in different directories..

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the nature of the other file, importing it may be a good solution.

```
from otherfile import big_function

for something something:
    big_function()
```

Comment: It's a tad better to use `frmo otherfile import big_function` itself, to avoid calling `otherfile.big_function` repeatedly (remember, each `.` is a function call in Python).

Comment: @PierreGM Good point. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `import` the other file (or only the function name from that file). Look at the [tutorial on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for reference. Don't forget that scripts are executed when you import them.